# Coercing a (previously) coerced interval into a character string back into an interval

Tags: r, lubridate

Lubridate's interval function together with its parsing functions allow us to obtain an interval from strings.

```
# An illustrative example.
my_interval = interval(dmy("15/07/2019"), dmy("15/07/2020"))
```

When printed, *my_interval* looks like this: 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC

Now, it is perfectly plausible to coerce an interval into a character string through the as.character function. However, what about the inverse? **Can an interval coerced into a character string be coerced back into an interval?**

Perhaps one may ask why would I want to coerce an interval into a character string in the first place. I actually have several intervals and I would like to obtain their combinations through the combn function.

```
# Suppose x is a vector of intervals. Then, what I would like to execute is
combn(x, 2) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(V1, V2))
```

However, when combn is applied onto a vector of intervals it —for some reason— returns a matrix of numbers. **Therefore, I see fit to first coerce my vector of intervals into a vector of characters and then, after having obtained the combinations of the strings, turn the strings back into intervals.**

Comment: `is.character(my_interval)
[1] FALSE` So you are appear to be falsely concluding that the my_interval object is something that can be treated as a character object. Given your lack of understanding of the underlying data representations, I think it essential that you post code to construct the data objects that you propose to work with. (Note: `is.numeric(my_interval)
[1] TRUE`)

Comment: @IRTFM, not quite. I know that my_interval is not a character. However, as.character(my_interval) is a character. Now, I'm asking if there exists a function (let's call it some_function) such that some_function(as.character(my_interval)) is identical to my_interval —i.e. returns an interval object—.

Comment: I'm not sure that `combn` will allow you preserve the attributes of interval objects. If the downstream code can handle straight numeric values (which it appears it won't), you may be able to proceed with your plan. (I adding the extra code obscured your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) character to interval** If ch is the character representation of my_interval then my_interval2 is the reconstruction of it from ch.  We test this with a vector of intervals, my_intervals.  This is also used in the other alternatives.

```
# test data
my_intervals <- rep(my_intervals, 3)

ch <- format(my_intervals)  # rep)"2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC", 3)

my_intervals2 <- interval(as.Date(ch), as.Date(sub(".*--", "", ch)))

identical(my_intervals, my_intervals2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) complex**  Instead of converting to character and back convert to complex and back. We use the same vector of intervals as above for testing.

```
library(zoo)

int2cplx <- function(x) c(cbind(as.Date(int_start(x)), as.Date(int_end(x))) %*% c(1,1i))
cplx2int <- function(x) interval(as.Date(Re(x)), as.Date(Im(x)))

my_intervals2 <- int2cplx(my_intervals)
identical(my_intervals, cplx2int(my_intervals2))
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) combn with indexes** If the only reason to convert back and forth between character and interval is to use combn then instead use combn over indexes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# given a 2-vector of indexes, e.g. 1:2, and vector of intervals this returns
#   1 row tibble with cols int1, int2, overlaps of classes interval, interval, logical
ovrlap <- function(index, intervals) {
  ints <- intervals[index]
  tibble(int1 = ints[[1]], int2 = ints[[2]], overlaps = int_overlaps(int1, int2))
} 

my_intervals %>%
  combn(length(.), 2, ovrlap, intervals = ., simplify = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  int1                           int2                           overlaps
  <Interval>                     <Interval>                     <lgl>   
1 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC TRUE    
2 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC TRUE    
3 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC TRUE
```

**4) list comprehension** Instead of using combn we could use the listcompr package to generate the result using list comprehensions

```
library(lubridate)
library(listcompr)

overlap <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  gen.data.frame(data.frame(int1 = x[i], int2 = x[j], 
    overlaps = int_overlaps(x[i], x[j])), i < j, i = 1:n, j = 1:n)
}

overlap(my_intervals)
```

giving

```
                             int1                           int2 overlaps
 1 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC     TRUE
 2 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC     TRUE
 3 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC     TRUE
```

Comment: I love the economy of your solutions. You look at the problem carefully and strive to minimize the code and maximize the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you pipe some string manipulation and create a user-defined function to do that.

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

#Example interval:

interval_char<-"2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC"

#transformation
char_to_interval<-function(char){
        char%>%str_split(., " UTC--")%>%
        unlist%>%
        str_remove(.,' UTC')%>%
        map(ymd)%>%
        pmap(.,interval)
}

char_to_interval(interval_char)


[1] 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have incorporated some aspects from the answers that were generously provided by GuedesBF and G.Grothendieck in order to craft a vectorized solution.

Suppose *x* is a vector of intervals. Then, we can get the combinations of the intervals by executing the following code:

```
combinations = combn(as.character(x), 2) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
```

The issue here is that we were forced to coerce *x* into a character vector in order to use the combn function. Now that we have already obtained the combinations, we require to turn our data back into intervals. We shall do just that through the following function:

```
char_2_interval = function(column) { 
     str_split(column, " UTC--", simplify = T) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
     mutate_all(as.Date) %>%
     transmute(interval(V1, V2)) %>% pull()
}
```

We will apply this function to all columns of the *combinations* data frame.

```
combinations = combinations %>% mutate_all(char_2_interval)
```

Now, we are able to discern all the overlaps between pairs of intervals, **which is indeed what I had wanted to do since the beginning.**

```
combinations = combinations %>% mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(V1, V2))
```